# Animation: Bones & Vertex

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I've animated a dome which opens using bones. The shell of the dome goes down into the ground. My problem is that when this dome is mounted on a tower, the player can see the shell going through the floor and walls. These shots might explain it better:

[image: one side of the dome in closed position]
[image: the dome in openend position, the shell going through the ground]
What I would like is the vertexes of the dome shell to 'pile up' at ground level, so they stay within the boundries of the physical model and not clip through walls or floors.

Since this is animated for Source, I'm bound to using bones. I thought of cutting up the shell into small sections so I can move them individually, but the Source skeleton system is quite rigid, so I can't bind all those individual sections to the same bone. Since it treats it like a skeleton it will always move the previous bone with it (like an actual arm works).

Any idea's how I could do this? I'm still quite new to animation...